Cursor disappearing inside text field
I'm encountering an unusual issue on Windows 10 and Windows 11 PCs where my mouse cursor disappears within any text field—whether on websites, in search bars, or similar fields in Chrome or other browsers. This made the text selection challenging since the cursor's position was uncertain. How can I solve this issue?
Tried turning on caret browsing in Chrome, but didn't work.

After some troubleshooting, I managed to resolve the issue.
Here’s how you can fix it:

Press Windows + R to open the Run dialog.
Type MAIN.CPL and hit OK.
In the Mouse Properties window, go to the Pointers tab.
Select Text Select from the Customize section.
Click Browse and choose beam_r from the list.
Apply that and click OK.

Good luck, hope it helps.!

Worked for me too on Windows 11, thank you! This was driving me crazy.

Always welcome!

I have Windows 10. With two monitors, the external one, that is the non laptop one, displayed the pointer, the laptop one was the one with this issue. I did your fix and it worked now it shows in both. Is beam_r.cur the default one for "none" scheme, which I had activated by default and so probably most of us? It looks the same.

FYI, I changed my windows theme and ended up having to do this again. I guess it reverted the pointer settings back.

This was driving me nuts on a docking station, guessing this is a laptop default or something. The hide pointer while typing box threw me off thinking it'd be a different mouse icon issue!

I had this problem for many days, I tried several solutions and only this one definitely worked! thank you so much

Dear lord I could hug you. You have no idea how long this has been bothering me. The worst was working with an online IDE and it wouldn't show the cursor at all. I was about to lose my mind. This solved it. THANK YOU.

Danke, helped me after I enabled HDR

I was having this same issue, and the answer from Alo works for me. In case it does not, you can simply change the cursor size from 1 to 2 in the windows settings:
Window + I > Accessibility > Mouse pointer and touch > Size > bump this up by 1.
This solution isn't ideal, but it does work as an alternative.

The answers sequence and count in a post is not fix. If you refer to one of them use some unique identifier for the other.

You may also want to check in your settings the HDR mode
Open Settings>System>Display>Advanced display. Look for automatically manage color for apps, this should be turned OFF.

This works better for me than the selected solution, because the beam_r has an annoying white border around it. Where turning off Auto Color Management keeps the fact that there are 2 beams, a white and black one that automatically applies depending on the background.
